# MySQL dump-restore replaces characters with 3Fh

Tags: mysql, backup, freebsd, restore, corruption

FreeBSD Server with Mysql and make.conf like that

```
.if ${.CURDIR} == ${PORTSDIR}/databases/mysql50-server
WITH_CHARSET=cp1251
WITH_COLLATION=cp1251_bin
BUILD_OPTIMIZED=yes
BUILD_STATIC=yes
.endif
.if ${.CURDIR} == ${PORTSDIR}/databases/mysql50-client
WITH_CHARSET=cp1251
WITH_COLLATION=cp1251_bin
BUILD_OPTIMIZED=yes
.endif
```

I have mysql table with such structure

```
mysql> show create table phpbb_bt_torrents\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: phpbb_bt_torrents
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `phpbb_bt_torrents` (
`info_hash` char(20) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128511 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

I'm backing it up at night with `mysqldump --quote-names --add-drop-table db>db.sql`

If I restore backup using `mysql < db.sql` *on the same server* then I'm getting not quite the same data, for example:

`SELECT hex(info_hash) FROM phpbb_bt_torrents`

8CB0701A0C8B7D976538**88**E8B959A6420AEC7679 becomes
8CB0701A0C8B7D976538**3F**E8B959A6420AEC7679 after restore

A9**98**6D2E961E1F407E74E9D18D811DDB702924F5 becomes
A9**3F**6D2E961E1F407E74E9D18D811DDB702924F5 after restore

and so on... i've noticed only 88h and 98h characters corrupts, but there can be more.

Is there a way to backup-restore data without corruption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened the ticket on [Bugs.MySQL.com](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46622)

Workaround from there:

> specify option
>   --default-character-set=cp1251. But this workaround would not work with
>   test case with mixed character sets

Answer (score 0):

Can you try dumping with "mysqldump --opt ..." and then restoring it?

It shouldn't make a difference when on the same server, just to make sure this cannot be some user-specific configuration.

Comment: as i know --opt is on by default